# HANA: How can I set the seed on the RAND() function?

Tags: sql, hana, hana-sql-script

I am trying to fix the pseudo random numbers generated by the RAND() function in HANA sqlscript.
I'm pretty sure it must be possible but the [documentation](http://help-legacy.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/e64d8675191014bba389d65920392d/content.htm) is not very explicit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no seeding option available for `RAND()` and neither for `RAND_SECURE()`.